# How to set optimized thresholds to turn a two-class data into a three-class data?

Tags: logistic, optimization, threshold

Let's say I have a column, (let us call it column $I$) that has two classes, $[-1,1]$. this column is the prediction of a classification model so it has vectors of probabilities that looks like, for example, this: $[0.3,0.7]$.

We have set two thresholds, $a$,$b$ to turn these two classes into three classes.

**For Example:**

Let $a=0.6$  and  $b=0.3$ and the probability of class "1" be $p$.

We define :

-If $p>0.6$ then the class is $1$

-If $0.6>p>0.3$ then the class is $0$

-If $0.3>p$ then the class is $-1$

...So by changing $a$ and $b$, we get different proportions of these three classes. We can check these new classes and calculate a score based on true values for each $a$ and $b$.

**Scoring:**

The Scoring is kind of complicated, but I don't think it completely necessary. but here it goes anyway:

Other than this three-class column of data ($I$), we have two other columns. they are both classed into two classes: $[-1,1]$. we call them: $J$ and $K$.

Here the scoring:

If $I=0$ : No Score

If $I≠J$ : No Score

If $I=J=K$ : +1 Score

If $I=J≠K$ : -1 Score

**Note: the column $I$ is the prediction of the column $K$ and $J$ is independent data**

**My Question:**

How to optimize the $a,b$ to get the highest score.
The simplest and probably the worst way is to run two for loops and hope for the best.
Is there an algorithmic way to optimize $a$ and $b$ to get the highest score? Something like gradient decent wouldn't work, because there is no function for score based on $a$ and $b$. We have to run all data to get a score.

A slight nudge in the right direction would do.

Comment: How are you scoring your decision?

Comment: My slight nudge would be that I don't think there is any more optimized way. If you knew something about the parameter space of A & B maybe we could do something-- for example, if it was a convex function, we could know that we were at a universal minimum. As it is, some sort of looping over thresholds is probably the best you can do.